# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Patrick Hoefler]
[image: Jeanne Holm]
[image: philshem]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

#### Update: November 17, 2016

Please thank [Joe](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/263/joe) for his contribution to the site. And welcome [philshem](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/1511/philshem) to the team.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! We'll do our best to make this place an informative and friendly home for the Open Data community. I very much look forward to working with all of you to bring a little more knowledge about Open Data into the world! :)

Comment: It's great to see such active participation from so many people across the world in open data. I look forward to all the contributions from each member here and the new members yet to join.

Comment: @Grace Note "you'll have your elections in several weeks". Several months have passed from that day. Do we have any news?

Comment: @Anastasios I'll have to fix that boilerplate text some time - elections happen after a site graduates, not based on any particular date range from entering public beta.

Comment: @GraceNote Thank you. Didn't know that :)

Comment: did i miss the elections? huge thanks to joe and phil!

Comment: @albert - there are no elections until the site is out of beta. I've taken over on a temporary basis. To get out of beta, we need to work on some stats like "unanswered questions"

Comment: ha. truth. congrats regardless, you deserve it